# Python WebScraping - I can navigate the website but the request returns '403'

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to Webscrape the website in the code, but I get a 403 code. I have searched all the topics regarding getting over this problem, and used the recommendations for defining the user agent, however it is still not working.

This is the code that I have tried.

```py
from requests import get

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36'}
idealista = 'https://www.idealista.pt/comprar-casas/lisboa-distrito/pagina-1'
response = get(idealista, headers=headers)
print(response)
```

It is returning "Response [403]". How can I get the 200 code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you still get forbidden, you should try adding more headers.

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0',
           'referer': 'https://www.idealista.pt/comprar-casas/lisboa-distrito/pagina-1' }
request = requests.get('https://www.idealista.pt/comprar-casas/lisboa-distrito/pagina-1', headers=headers)
```

output

```
<Response [200]>
```